# C# - Use RedirectToAction from a method instead of an ActionView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a method that I can call from all the `catch` section in my controller, that is redirected to `Error` action of `Home` controller. The method and the catch statement together in a `Controller` would look like this:

```
public class myController : Controller
{

     public RETURNTYPE redirectMethod(Exception e)
     {
          //Using e for logging methods
          RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          try
          {
              <!-- try statement -->
          }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
              redirectMethod(e);
         }

     return View();
     }
}
```

Obviously i have a lot of other codes in my redirectMethod, else I would have simply used RedirectToAction directly in my catch phrase. Could anyone help me on what my return type of the `redirectMethod` should be, and if `RedirectToAction` doesn't work inside a method (instead of ActionResult), then what should I use?

Comment: It should be an `ActionResult`

Comment: Error handling in MVC is a separate topic. And what you do there is suboptimal. There are better ways: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging  http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/45  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1068/aspnet-mvc-exception-handling http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you could use:

```
protected ActionResult redirectMethod(Exception e)
{
    //Using e for logging methods
    return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        <!-- try statement -->
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return redirectMethod(e);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Note that this is still not ideal. The URL where the error occurred gets lost, so users can not report it, and doing a refresh to retry won't work for the same reason.

Comment: No this isn't redirecting me anywhere.

Comment: The `RedirectToAction`-call implies that there is a class `HomeController`, with an Action method called `Error`. And typically a View also with that name. I assumed that you already had that, or if not, then you can add them now, and then it should work.

Comment: Oops, I oversaw the return part of catch statement.  It works now, but like you said, the message gets lost (which I had set in TempData). If I set the redirectMethod in the same controller where I am calling it from, the TempData message doesn't get lost, but I am trying to call all the errors from one ErrorController, which loses the TempData message.

Answer (score 3):

The `RedirectToAction()` method return an object of type `RedirectToRouteResult` which inherits from `ActionResult` so you can use any of them as a return type. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirecttorouteresult(v=vs.118).aspx) for more info.